# Intersection of two Feature Collections in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, intersection, feature-collection

I am trying a very easy problem in GIS, but I cannot deal with in GEE. My goal is to get a resulting FeatureCollection with two properties (VH and class) initially contained in two different FeatureCollections (binary_vector and eval_merged). In any GIS tool I would solve this by intersecting both FeatureCollections, resulting in a new FeatureCollection containing both properties. However, I do not know how to deal with in GEE.

I have tried using the intersection, but it requires a Feature instead of a FeatureCollection, therefore the possible solution would be to do two map functions to intersect every Feature in FeatureCollection binary_vector with every Feature in FeatureCollection in eval_merged).

I have also tried by using a spatial filter but raises an error: 'User memory limit exceeded'.

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

**CODE USING THE SPATIAL FILTER:**

```
//binary_vector and eval_merged are two FeatureCollections

var spatial_filter = ee.Filter.intersects({
leftField: '.geo',
rightField: '.geo'
});

var saveAllJoin = ee.Join.saveAll({
matchesKey: 'id'
});

var intersectJoined = saveAllJoin.apply(binary_vector,eval_merged,spatial_filter);
```

It raises the error of memory limit when applyng the spatial filter.

Comment: Can you share a working example where you show what you tried?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code lines of the spatial join. Actually, I do not know what ee.Join.saveAll does and what is the matchesKey parameter.

Comment: Probably go through the documentation then: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/joins_save_all. Also, by working example it is often suggested that you provide a script that works and shows where your problem is. Because user memory limit exceeded is generic error that can have multiple causes. Most likely the geometries you are using are complex or large (lots of vertices to work with)..